# SQL table auxiliary, Every table contains auxiliary in the Database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle-xe

I never heard about this auxiliary:

```
SQL> select * from customer;

CUSTID CUSTNAME       VDUMMY

   504 customer4         101
   505 customer5         101
   506 customer6         101

SQL> select * from customer auxillary;

CUSTID CUSTNAME       VDUMMY

   504 customer4         101
   505 customer5         101
   506 customer6         101
```

- Every table contains auxillary table in the database?
- What is auxiliary?
- If we delete the original table, will the auxiliary table get deleted?

Comment: You tagged the question as mySQL and SQL Server. Which platform are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL, is auxillary is database dependent ?

Comment: SQL is ***not*** a database product. It's a query language. So which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Answer (score 4):

The word after "customer" is not a table. It's just an alias name you can give to any table in your query. It's used to identify columns with the same name when using (i.e. joining) multiple tables like so:

```
select * from table1 t1 
   inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

In SQL Server you could write your second query also as

```
select * from customer as auxiliary
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a alias of the customer table. It can be anything like "customeralias" It auxiliary is the short and sweet name of the table.